# How to separate application.conf to multiply conf files in play framework 1.3

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

Is it possible to use the include feature in as apache properties files in play framework 1.3?
I want each developer to have his/her own conf file instead of using application.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any documentation for it but found the answer in play source (https://github.com/playframework/play1/blob/master/framework/src/play/Play.java)

You can use the @include key word, example application.conf file would be

```
myproperty=myvalue

@include.shared=application_tzach.conf
```

and in application_tzach.conf do:

```
%tzach.myproperty=tzach_property
```